# PHP - Expired cookie still returned as set?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

New to PHP and HTML so need an advice.

I am having a weird behavior.
After user logs in on (1)login page of the website i am creating the cookie and sending him to the (2)Mainmenu page of the website.

Here's the code:

...

```
if (checkUser($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]) == true)

{

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value,time()+60);  /*expire in 1min */
    header("Location: main.html");
    exit;
}
```

...

Then after hitting other links on that page(2) i want to be able to check whether the user is still logged in or his cookie expired.

So on start of every php page of the website i'm calling for a checking method in order to see if the cookie is still set or expired:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))           //cookie exists

**PART A**
{

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cookie exists');</script>";

}

else                            // no cookie/expired

**PART B**
{

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cookie expired!')</script>";    

}
```

***PROBLEM:*** 
even after cookie expired(IE debug(F12) shows me that it dissapeared after 1 min),closing the browser and starting it again,if i open the website and check if the cookie is set the answer is always **'Cookie exists'**

So i can't handle expiration and can't enter the **PART B**....

Any suggestions guys?
Thanks.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);` show?

Comment: It prints:
string(8) "cookie11"

tha'ts the value of  = $cookie_name.

Even after expiration it keeps on printing it.